# Connect to hidden WiFi "network", transmit data and reconnect to original network

Tags: windows, esp8266, wifi-direct, esp8266wifi

I have very little experience with non-embedded programming, so i wanted to do a sanity check before I go down this path.

Basically just need to know whether the titular line of actions are possible to do as **a 1-click solution in Windows**:

- Disconnect from current WiFi Network.
- Connect to hidden network (An ESP8266).
- Transmit data.
- Disconnect from hidden network.
- Reconnect to original network, **which may be any network**.

I am not looking for someone to make this for me, I just need to know whether i have to change approach :)

To clarify a bit, the fans on my Lenovo Legion y530 is a pain in my backside, and there doesn't seem to be a way to fix it in software/bios.
So i have decided to make a small, non-intrusive ESP8266 based board that goes between the fans and motherboard, to smooth out the changes in fan-speed, and force the fans to stay above certain speed.

My problem is, i want to be able to adjust this minimal fan speed, as well as the size of the averaging on the PWM signal from the motherboard, so i need to be able to communicate with the ESP8266, without modifying existing hardware on the laptop (and without having to take it apart).

I could go with an ESP32 and use bluetooth, but that would quadrouple the hardware cost, so rather use the 8266.

Comment: Why do you need to disconnect from exiting network? Configure your ESP8266 (same subnet) to be on the same network as your Windows and as a [web server](https://github.com/esp8266/ESPWebServer) and write some code so that you can access the web server and control the speed like `http://<esp8266_ip>/?speed=xxx` via a browser.

Comment: Because it is my study laptop, i move it around between home and a couple of campus', so having the ESP connected to the network is generally not doable.